# Create JWT Token within UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter or Controller?

Tags: java, spring, security, jwt, token

I try to generate a JWT Token with Spring Security but I don't how to do it correctly (with the best practice).

Do I should "intercept" the authenticate method within UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter somewhere and generate token inside it ?
Or it is better to use AuthenticationManager autowired in the controller '/login' ?

I'm afraid to authenticate the user twice if I use the controller mechanism.

I used this tutorial : [tutorial Jwt Token](https://medium.com/@hantsy/protect-rest-apis-with-spring-security-and-jwt-5fbc90305cc5)

Here is my code :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

//  @Autowired
//  private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/login/**", "/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")      
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            //.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("email")
                //.loginPage("http://localhost:4200/login").failureUrl("/login-error")  
                .and()
            .logout() 
                .permitAll();
        http
            .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebConfig() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                                "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Authorization", "Cache-Control",
                                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Token Filter

```
public class JwtTokenFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    public JwtTokenFilter(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) req);
        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
            Authentication auth = token != null ? jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token) : null;
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Token Provider

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret}")
    private String secretKey = "secret";

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.expire-length:3600000}")
    private long validityInMilliseconds = 3600000; // 1h    

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    }

    public String createToken(String username, List<String> roles) {

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        claims.put("roles", roles);
        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliseconds);
        return Jwts.builder()//
                    .setClaims(claims)//
                    .setIssuedAt(now)//
                    .setExpiration(validity)//
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secretKey)//
                    .compact();
    }

    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getUsername(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    public String getUsername(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(token);
            if (claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new InvalidJwtAuthenticationException("Expired or invalid JWT token");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your context, the controller is responsible for issuing a new token (after validating credentials) while the filter is responsible for authenticating the user against the given token. The controller should not populate the security context (authenticate user), it is the filter's responsibility.

*To better understand the two phases:*

Spring uses two filters to authenticate and log in a user.
See [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java) and [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java)  in a "username/password" scenario, from the Spring Security project: the first one processes an authentication attempt (username/password) while the latter populates the security context from a `SecurityContextRepository` (from a session in general).

Comment: I prefer filters than controllers as well. Is it possible to use these two filters with a post request on a login controller ? The request is managed by a controller who build an Authentication object which is sent to the filters (authenticate() then generateToken()). I will check your links.

Comment: You can't call a filter from a controller (as a request first goes through a series of filters, then through an appropriate controller). As you need to return a token on a successful authentication request, your best option remains to use a controller who is responsible for issuing a new token (with the use of an `AuthenticationManager`). Then, to authenticate the user against a given token, simply use a `JWTAuthenticationFilter`.